# What is the Twilio's request body sent to the Customer Profile status callback URL?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm interested in the process of onboarding customers into the A2P-10DLC campaigns.

I'm reading the documentation for the *[Secondary Customer Profile creation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv-api)* using the Twilio Trusthub API.

I see that I can provide a status callback URL as part of the customer profile creation process, as described [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv-api#12-create-an-empty-secondary-customer-profile-bundle).

The Trusthub API documentation mentions after the customer profile has been submitted for review, it will notify the `status_callback` URL with the status changes. That is described [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/trust-hub/trusthub-rest-api/api-create-secondary-customer-profile#step-15).

My question is: Where can I see the contract of the request body sent by Twilio to the `status_callback` URL after the customer profile has been reviewed?

I been reading the Twilio A2P-10DLC documentation for onboarding clients and the TrustHub API reference, but I can't seem to find the data contract I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not locate either...And, I checked through the various github respositories. But, if I had to guess, the status_callback payload will be the same or similar to the one shown in the example "[Submit for Review](https://www.twilio.com/docs/trust-hub/trusthub-rest-api/api-create-secondary-customer-profile?code-sample=code-submit-for-review&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x)":

```
{
  "sid": "BUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "account_sid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "policy_sid": "RNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "friendly_name": "friendly_name",
  "status": "pending-review",
  "email": "email",
  "status_callback": "http://www.example.com",
  "valid_until": null,
  "date_created": "2019-07-30T22:29:24Z",
  "date_updated": "2019-07-31T01:09:00Z",
  "url": "https://trusthub.twilio.com/v1/CustomerProfiles/BUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "links": {
    "customer_profiles_entity_assignments": "https://trusthub.twilio.com/v1/CustomerProfiles/BUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/EntityAssignments",
    "customer_profiles_evaluations": "https://trusthub.twilio.com/v1/CustomerProfiles/BUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Evaluations",
    "customer_profiles_channel_endpoint_assignment": "https://trusthub.twilio.com/v1/CustomerProfiles/BUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/ChannelEndpointAssignments"
  }
}
```

Friendly reminder that [Twilio Webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request) are in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format - not JSON. You will have to parse and create your own contract. For example:

> https://yourrequestbinendpoint.com/sid=BUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&account_sid=ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&policy_sid=RNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&friendly_name=friendly_name&status=pending-review&email=email&status_callback=http://www.example.com&valid_until=&date_created=2019-07-30T22:29:24Z&date_updated=2019-07-31T01:09:00Z

You can confirm the webhook payload by creating a secondard profile, setting the status_callback to an endpoint that will capture and collect any traffic such as a [requestbin](https://pipedream.com/requestbin).

A last option to consider is opening a ticket, asking Twilio Support for the webhook payload and asking them to update the public documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think your suggestion of requestbin will be helpful to me when integrating this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio customer profile webhook headers is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 Still you can expect the below request body if your endpoint header is set to JSON

```
AccountSid:XXXXX
BundleSid:BBBBB
FailureReason:
Status:in-review
```